# HashMap Display Of String[] In ListView

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I'm trying to display some String[] values in a listview through a hashmap. When I go to try to display this, the values themselves arent displayed but a random display of numbers is displayed [Ljava.lang.String;@....."]. My relevant code is below:

```
//NEW TEST STUFF
    feedList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String[]>>();
    map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

//TEST ARRAYS
    a = new String[] {"a","b"};
    b = new String[] {"c", "d"};

//NEW STUFF
    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, feedList, R.layout.list_view, new String[]{"one", "two"}, new int[]{R.id.companyListViewColumn, R.id.colorListViewColumn});


map.put("one", a);
map.put("two", b);
feedList.add(map);

crossReferenceListView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

What is causing this???

Comment: Try changing the order. Write map.put() first and simpleAdapter =new.... after that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead if you need order. [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) has no order.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you inserted more keys in string so Hashmap always refers new assigned key. Hashmap don't allows you to store key data type to String[]. Use **HashTable** for storing multiple keys and values.